2 linear actuators getting start stop signal from the same switch. is that possible?
Hello all and thanks in advance for your time.
I'm a total newbie.
I want to build an automated procedure without doing complex programming.
Ideally I would like to have:
1 linear actuator (LA1), a rotating motor (RM1) and 3 limit switches (SW1, SW2 and SW3) -> SW2 & SW3 should have a double role. Actuator and motor should have a manual controller.

Start button is pressed.
LA1 starts the travel from the position of SW1 and travels till it reaches SW2.
SW2 triggers LA1 to start to travel back and at the same time triggers RM1 spins at the specified travel setting
LA1 reaches SW1 position

and that's one cycle
when x cycles are completed the mechanism will reach SW3 position
-that triggers both LA1 and RM1 to stop
Am I dreaming or is the double role possible without special programming?
Special hardware required?

This is the perfect job for a PLC. Anything worth doing will require some programming. But the PLC ladder logic is very basic "pseudo-programming"

A picture of your setup would be useful outlining the parts/specs that you plan on designing.

It sounds like a basic custom router table but only 2 axis ( one linear and one rotary) instead of a 3 axis XYZ table with a fixed router speed.  Can you define "travel" as speed, RPM, feed rate, or some other parameter and fill in the gaps for speed acceleration, torque mass, and size as required in a list and describe functions?  The language can be graphical or simply fixed speed acceleration and X positions or GUI interface with simple G text code for position but RPM is not part of standard gantries.  The switch may need an intermediate stop command pause before reversing.

A diagram of the positions of SW1, SW2 and SW3 along the axis of travel , please. It's unclear where SW3 is in all this. Also, I don't understand what you mean by "double role". From your description, the switch roles are clear(ish), and none of them are double.
